# Could Spring Cloud Config Server be used for getting plain resource (not merged with application config)

Tags: yaml, spring-cloud

I have application configuration files, which inherited from common application.yml configuration. The question is can I have some resources which will be fetched without merging with another configuration? Some yml file to get it as is without any modifications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding another repository (pattern based) without application.yml common config file in it - works for me.

```
    config:
  server:
    git:
      uri: http://host:port/configuration/git/app.git
      username: configserver
      password: password
      repos:
         data-config:
             uri: http://host:port/configuration/data-config.git
             username: configserver
             password: password
             pattern: data_*
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the new searchPaths setting since 1.0.1

```html
config:
  server:
git:
  uri: http://host:port/configuration/git/app.git
  repos:
     team1-config:
         uri: http://host:port/configuration/config.git
         searchPaths: team1*
         pattern: team1_*
     team2-config:
         uri: http://host:port/configuration/config.git
         searchPaths: team2*
         pattern: team2_*
```

By using searchPath, you can keep everything within a config-repo but divided into different folder.  Potentially, each folder for a different project.